# Link field not included when pulling group post

Tags: facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the group post with ID 122293914785208_224232567924675 (i.e. https://www.facebook.com/122293914785208_224366181244647) from the graph API (it's just the first busy public group I found in New York, please don't read in to my politics :) ).

Issuing a GET on `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/122293914785208_224366181244647?access_token=<my_token>` gives me the body

```
{
    "created_time": "2016-02-19T12:46:31+0000",
    "id": "122293914785208_224366181244647",
    "message": "Trump again being proven right."
}
```

I'm surprised that there isn't a link field, pointing to the news article, and I'm not sure how to get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
**POST ID: 224366181244647, GROUP ID: 122293914785208**

//-- You need to specify what you need in the query Params
//-- example: ?fields=link,message,id

/*------------------------ response:
{
 "link": "{post_link_facebook}",
 "id": "122293914785208_224366181244647",
 "message": "Trump again being proven right."
}
-----------------------------------*/

#Facebook get post graph-api#
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{POST ID}??fields=link,message,id&access_token={my_token}

#Facebook get group graph-api#
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{GROUP ID}?access_token={my_token}

#Facebook get group posts graph-api#
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{GROUP ID}/feed?access_token={my_token}


#Facebook post url: Example#
https://www.facebook.com/groups/122293914785208/permalink/224366181244647
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... getting on the post URI you've given still doesn't return me a link

Comment: Try Here [Graph api explorer tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=224366181244647%3Ffields%3Did%2Cmessage%2Clink&version=v2.5)

Comment: I think I understand what you're getting at - I need to specify that I want the link field in the query params e.g. with `?fields=link,message` if I need the link and message. That seems to work, eitherway. If that's what you meant, can you edit your answer to reflect it so I can accept it?